# How To concat an Object and Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a user with a favorites array

I am trying to concat an item to the favorites field.

Here I assign the user to `userToChange` variable

```
const userToChange = action.data.user;
```

And here I concat a 'card to the user's `favorites` field

```
const changedUserFavorites = userToChange.favorites.concat(action.data.card);
```

I need to pass the updated user field to an axios update call. I have tried to concat the user and the updated favorites field like this.

```
 const changedUser = userToChange.concat(changedUserFavorites);
```

but I am getting an error: ×

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): userToChange.concat is not a function
```

I suspect this might be due to the fact that userToChange is an object

Here is what `userToChange` looks like:

```
User to Change 
Object
favorites: [Array(1)]
firstName: "phil"
id: "5de9930fedc70846747305f6"
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InBoaWwiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJwaGlsIiwiaWF0IjoxNTc1NTkwNDkwfQ.SYoApD4FUuXDEhjWSDBg0_gkKmf7a2FHm5Yifu2yhgw"
username: "phil"
__proto__: Object
```

and `changedUserFavorites` is an Array.

Thus, I just wonder how can I put the two together given that one field is an object?

Comment: `Object.assign` can be your friend.

Comment: You cannot `.concat()` to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For objects, you can use `Object.assign` to append properties onto an existing object.

```
let myObj = { a: 1 }
let newObj = { b: 1 }
Object.assign(myObj, newObj)
///myObj = { a: 1, b:1 }
```

For arrays, you have the `Array.prototype.concat` method.

```
let myArr = [1, 2]
myArr.concat([3, 4])
//myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

MDN

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat